# AWS DMS validation fails if primary key contains boolean column

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-dms

I am trying to migrate data from an on prem SQL Server DB to Postgres Aurora using AWS DMS. The data migrates just fine, but for tables that have a boolean column in the primary key, during validation it fails with the following error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
```

Upon checking the logs on the Postgres side, I find this:

`ERROR: invalid input syntax for type boolean: "" at character <number>`

`STATEMENT: SELECT cast ("pcode" as varchar(6)) , "other_columns" , "boolean_column" FROM "db"."table" WHERE ((("boolean_column" = '' AND "pcode" > 'L7L3V9') AND ("boolean_column" = '' AND "pcode" <= 'L8L4E8'))) ORDER BY "boolean_column" ASC , "pcode" ASC`

During validation, it's fetching the records from the postgres in batches, and for each batch it uses the wrong value for the "bolean_column" (comparing to '' - blank string). I am not sure why it's doing this, or how to influence this behaviour so that the validations will be performed successfully.

The boolean column is a:

- bit field on the SQL Server side
- on postgres side, have tried converting to (both with same validation error as above):

  - numeric with precision 1
  - boolean
  - bit (after T N's comment below)

Comment: On searching for "sql server to postgresql data types mapping", I got mixed rsome recommended smallint esults. Some recomended boolean, at least one recommended smallint, bit [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sql-server-to-aurora-postgresql-migration-playbook/chap-sql-server-aurora-pg.sql.datatypes.html) indicates that PostgreSQL supports a BIT type. Is that an option to you? (I do not know PostgreSQL, so I can only provide this as a shot in the dark, since you haven't gotten any other responses.)

Comment: I have tried bit as well, and that doesn't seem to work either. `smallint` seems wrong to me honestly, it really just needs to be a boolean. For now, I've decided to skip validation by the AWS DMS service. I may do some manual validation myself.

Comment: And thanks for the manual link @TN, didn't know that existed.